# Username and password in database.yml file ignored if not root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to run a RoR app and it seems to be ignoring my username and password if it isn't root, any thoughts?

If it is configured as below, it works:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: dbname
  user: root
  password: root_password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

However, if it is set up with a non root user, it fails with the message *`connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)*

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: dbname
  user: username
  password: username_password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

`mysql -uusername -p<username password> <dbname>` connects without any issue.  Specifying a `host` or `hostname` doesn't fix it.

**Update**

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: dbname
  user: root
  # username
  password: root_password
  # username_password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: dbname
  user: username
  password: username_password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

results of running `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails c`

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
irb(main):001:0>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you've created your new `username` in MySQL with all privileges on the `dbname` database?

Comment: Are you sure you've updated your database.yml file with the user `username` because your error for some reason still lists `root@localhost` ?

Comment: @momer yes, I checked in the mysql table in mysql, and it's there.  Then I logged in via the command and was able to insert/update/delete.

Comment: Have you tried `host: 127.0.0.1`? Note: this is not the same as `host: localhost`

Comment: @JasdeepSingh yes, i'm ssh'ed into the server, changes are live. The directory is a git repo, and I don't always commit the file, but this shouldn't matter since if I change the file to the root/rootpassword combo it works.

Comment: @Momer yes, I tried that as well.  the port is the standard 3306 as well.

Comment: Please paste your entire `database.yml`. Also try `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails c` and let us know the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My database.yml was out dated(set up incorrectly).  `user` is not the correct key, it is `username`.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: dbname
  username: root
  # username
  password: root_password
  # username_password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: dbname
  username: username
  password: username_password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```